# Show CPU activity in Timeline in current Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome v38. I've been reading [an article which recommends enabling "Timeline: Show CPU Activity on the Ruler"](https://plus.google.com/+NatDuca/posts/BvMgvdnBvaQ?e=-RedirectToSandbox) in the DevTools settings.

However, this setting option no longer seems to exist in current DevTools:

[image]

How can I show CPU activity in new DevTools? I can't see any options in the Timeline section relating to this, and I'd really like to debug what's going on with my timeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the CPU time in the recordings by default now. There is no need to enable a setting for this. You can read more about it in the docs here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline#view-cpu-time-in-recordings

[image]